# How to map multiple subdomains to single instance of MERN Multi tenant app?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, react-router, subdomain, multi-tenant

I am building a multi tenant app using `MERN stack`. While learning about best practices to identify tenant, i fixed on subdomain approach. For example, on browsing URL like

1. `tenant1.mydomain.com,`
2. `tenant2.mydomain.com`

etc., the `tenant1/tenant2` part of the URL is extracted as tenant identity to further authenticate users and start the app. As mentioned on https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2292#issuecomment-302894212, i set up .env so CRA (`npm run start`) development server can serve on mapped domain instead of default `localhost:3000` on development machine.

I suppose the approach works only for single tenant due to single subdomain mapping in .env, but don't know if and how multiple tenants can be taken care of. This whole stuff is new to me and i appreciate all possible help i can get to achieve multi tenancy goal.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, I particularly create a redirection of the subdomains to my main application domain. And this works for both development and production.

> Initially I left it in fixed development like you did, but now I do it
> as if it were in production, it makes the development more dynamic and
> real.

On any system you have the HOST file.

**Their path is usually in:**

- Windows 10: “C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts”
- Linux: “/etc/hosts”
- Mac OS X: “/private/etc/hosts”

In the HOST file I point the subdomains to my local ip or application ip. Something like:

127.0.0.1 client1.myapp.com

127.0.0.1 client2.myapp.com

127.0.0.1 client3.myapp.com

In this case it's local but it works for production, so when I run my app I don't need to use 127.0.0.1 or localhost, I can use one of those domains, and even if they point to the same IP, that way I can get the domain from the client inside application, such as:

```js
const domainName = window.location.hostname;
```

And now just use the domain to make the multitenancy logic work.